# How can i grab the imbdID, from my data file and add it to the correct URL, to the later on load it on to my screen using the DOM?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The assignment: Nice then only the last requirement: next to a   tag you want to wrap the posters of the films in one   with href the link of IMDB + the imdbID.

I have all my imbdID, in a dataBase.js.
Now how can I grab the correct imbdID and add it to the URL to then put on the href:

What I was trying to do, was to put all the imbdIDs in a variable, and then loop over them and put the URL, but it's not working.

```js
    const correctImbd = function (array) {
    let imbdList = array.map((item) => {
        return item.imdbID
    })
        imbdList.forEach((id) => {
        let url = "https://www.imdb.com/title/?" + id
    })
```

Later when caling to add to the DOM:

```js
    const addMoviesToDom = function (array) {
    MovieList.innerHTML = ""
    let films = array.map((item) => {
        return item.Poster
    })
    films.forEach((array) => {
        let newLi = document.createElement("img")
        let newA = document.createElement("a")
        MovieList.appendChild(newA)
        newA.appendChild(newLi)
        newLi.src = array
        newA.href = correctImbd(movies)
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing nothing with `url` besides initialize it. Also avoid iterating multiple times over the same array.
I would forget about the first part of the code and just simply the next one, resulting in:

```
let films = array.map((item) => {
  return {
    id: item.imdbID,
    poster: item.Poster
  }
});

films.forEach((film) => {
  let newLi = document.createElement("img")
  let newA = document.createElement("a")
  MovieList.appendChild(newA)
  newA.appendChild(newLi)
  newLi.src = film.poster
  newA.href = "https://www.imdb.com/title/?" + film.id
});
```